# How to generate a android.jar for mocking?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, mockito, android-testing

Now I need a mockable android.jar. I had ever seen a android.jar before generated automatically by mockito or gradle or android studio. How I can generate it in gralde task? I try ./gradlew mockableAndroidJar, but not android.jar finded.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that. You need an implementation of the android classes which only available on an actual phone.

You could try using Robolectric for this. http://robolectric.org/

Comment: But I had ever seen a android.jar generated automatically in the process of using mockito. I donot need a test framework or tool. Just for a way for android.jar

Comment: You have a different one for all version you can find them on a path similar to this: ..\Android\sdk\platforms\android-23\, but they are not exactly the same as on a phone

Answer (score 0):

Running the `mockableAndroidJar` Gradle Task should generate the `mockable-android-XX.jar` file in the `build/generated` folder of your workspace. It's possible that the `mockableAndroidJar` Gradle Task estimates that it is up to date and therefore is not generating the file. If this is the case then you can force run the Gradle Task by means of this command:

```
gradle mockableAndroidJar --rerun-tasks
```